# How can I setup a TextView to center text in the remaining available space?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm designing the title bar for a general purpose popup window, that features a button in the top left corner, a button in the top right corner, and a title textview sandwiched between them.  (The buttons are not simple android.widget.Buttons, but instead, at the moment, fragments.)

The two buttons need to be 'wrap_content' because the actual text/contents in them changes from instance to instance.  Critically, the two buttons may not be the same width.  As a result, the "remaining space" between them, bookended by "A" and "B" below, is not centered within the surrounding view; but I would like to put the title text in that space so that it is centered within the surrounding view.

If I do this naively, say using a LinearLayout with the title text having non-zero layoutWeight (so it fills up the remaining space), the text becomes off center:

```
                        A                                        B
[ Button 1 (ExtraSpace) ] [ ____________Title Text____________ ] [ Button 2 ]
                                      ^
                                      |
                                      |
                               center of window
```

What I would prefer is to somehow size Button 1 and Button 2 so that they have the same width, essentially adding a margin/padding/spacer view/relativelayout-magic/etc. to whichever would normally be narrower.  This would leave the Title Text actually centered within the dialog:

```
                        A                                        B
[ Button 1 (ExtraSpace) ] [ _____Title Text______ ] [ (ExtraSpace) Button 2 ]
                                      ^
                                      |
                                      |
                               center of window
```

I could alternatively just position/size the title text independently of the buttons; but it's important that the text is positioned and if necessary ellipsized correctly with respect to the two buttons' contents, so that I don't end up trying to display title text on top of the two buttons.

Comment: The only way I was able to achieve this was with static sizes of the buttons - ie I gave them a minWidth that was to never be exceeded and then used layout weights.

Comment: I was able to get at least something working, though it was a lot of code, by using getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(), checking to see if Button 1 or Button 2 had changed size, and resizing two spacer views injected between the Buttons and the title text as necessary.  It feels like a hack; but if nobody has a better suggestion after a few days from now, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use a LinearLayout with orientation set to **horizontal** to contain the two Buttons and the TextView.
Then give all your Views a layout_weight of **1** and a layout_width of **0dp**.

By doing so, all your Views will be evenly sized at **33% width** each

Comment: This is ok, but not great.  In my intended use, Button 1 and Button 2 might each take up as much as 50% of the total width, or as little as 0%.

Comment: And what about the TextView? If you remove it, with my proposed method, the buttons will also "take the TextView space" and both be **50%** in width, now!